# limits and L'Hospital's rule

Tags: calculus

$$\lim_{x\to 0^{+}} \frac{1+x\ln x}{x}$$

I think it is an indeterminate form so I applied the L'H rule and did the derivative of numerator and denominator and got limit as x tends to 0 from right [ $\ln (x) + 1$ ] which clearly shows that it depends on $\ln$ function. we know that $\ln$ function is negative infinity on zero plus but when I put this function in WolframAlpha I get positive infinity as the limit of the function. can somebody explain where am I going wrong?

Comment: Wait. "It is clearly an indeterminate form". What is $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} x\ln x$?

Comment: It clearly isn't.

Comment: It'd be in indeterminate form if $\lim (1+x\ln x) = 0$ or if $\lim x\ln x = -1$ but what the limit of $x\ln x$ itself is indeterminate.  so need to use L'hopital for $x\ln x$.... which *could* be $-1$ but isn't like.  .... Note: "indeterminate" does not mean "can't be done directly".

Comment: Dope slap to me  $\lim \frac {1 + x\ln x } x = \lim (\frac 1x + \ln x)$ which is *definately* *NOT* indeterminate.  $\frac 1x \to \infty$ and $\ln x \to -\infty$ but surely $\frac 1x \to \infty$ "faster" than $\ln x \to -\infty$ so the limit is positive infinity.

Comment: ahh okay thanks fleablood

Comment: Not that is serves as a rigorous proof, but if you graph the given function, you can see that the y-axis is a vertical asymptote.

Comment: If you think of $\lim x\ln x$ as $\lim x \lim \ln x$ you get "the form" $0\cdot( -\infty)$ which is indeterminate. To put this as a fraction $\lim x\ln x =\lim \frac{\ln x}{x^{-1}}$ which yields "the form" $\frac {-\infty}{\infty}$.  Applying L'hoptital we get $\lim\frac {x^{-1}}{-x^{-2}}=\lim -x=0$.  so $\lim 1+x\ln x = 1$ and $\lim x = 0$ and so $\lim \frac {1 + x\ln x}x$ is of the form $\frac 10$ which is not indeterminate.  So $\lim \frac {1 + x\ln x}x=\infty$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To apply L'Hôpital, you need your limit to be of the form $0/0$ or $\infty/\infty$. Your limit is neither: the numerator converges to $1$ and the denominator converges to $0$. As the limit is one-sided, so $x>0$, the limit equal $+\infty$.

If you don't know the limit of $x\ln x$, one way to do this limit is to substitute $x=1/t$. Then the limit becomes
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{\ln 1/t}{t}=-\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{\ln t}t=0
$$
(this last one, you can do by L'Hôpital if you need to).

Comment: " you need your limit to be of the form 0/0 or ∞/∞"  Or $0\times \infty$

Answer (score 1):

To make thing a bit easier for you, let's convert it to a $e$ expression ! So put $y = -\ln x \implies x = e^{-y} \implies \displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0{+}} \dfrac{1+ x\ln x}{x}= \displaystyle \lim_{y \to +\infty} \dfrac{1-ye^{-y}}{e^{-y}} = \displaystyle \lim_{y \to +\infty} (e^y - y)=\displaystyle \lim_{y \to +\infty} e^y\cdot \displaystyle \lim_{y \to +\infty} \left(1 - \dfrac{y}{e^y}\right)= +\infty\cdot 1 = +\infty $, by a simple L'hospital rule for the fraction $\dfrac{y}{e^y} \to 0$.

Comment: how do type math so nicely

Comment: @MeharjeetSingh: I used MathJax. Look up some simple commands and practice them. Open and close by the dollar sign. That's all.